# VBA scraping data in ticketing

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am a very new beginner in vba and want to scrape some data in a ticketing website.
Since I can scrape the ticketing data in the tag of `option` and put them all in column B, each `<li class="mobile">` have a showname in the tag of `<h3>`

Here is the html code:

```
<li class="mobile">
  <form>
   <h3>showname A</h3>
   <p class="tickeing">
     <select class="sec">
      <option value="19351">showtime 1</option>
      <option value="19381">showtime 2</option>
     </select>
   </p>
  </form>
</li>
<li class="mobile">
  <form>
   <h3>showname B</h3>
   <p class="tickeing">
     <select class="sec">
      <option value="19031">showtime 1</option>
      <option value="19231">showtime 2</option>
     </select>
   </p>
  </form>
</li>
```

and I can only put all the showtimes in column B

```
Dim Times As Object
Set Times = html.querySelectorAll("li.mobile option")
 For i = 0 To Times.Length - 1
 wsOne.Range("B" & i) = Times.Item(i).innerText
 Next i
```

My goal is putting the showname in column A and the related showtime(s) in column B, how can I solve it?

```
column A       column B
Show name A    Show time 1
Show name A    Show time 2
Show name B    Show time 1
Show name B    Show time 2
```

I am really appreciated if you can help me, many thanks.

Comment: You might wanna share the site link if that is not a problem.

Comment: Dear SIM, here is the site link [link] (https://www.uacinemas.com.hk/eng/cinema/1101) , hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this should do what you are trying to achieve.

```
Sub fetchContent()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.uacinemas.com.hk/eng/cinema/1101"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim Http As Object, sName$, N&, R&, I&
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With Http
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        With Html.querySelectorAll("li.mobile")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .Item(I).outerHTML
                sName = Htmldoc.querySelector("h3 > a").innerText
                With Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("p.tickeing > select > option")
                    For N = 0 To .Length - 1
                        R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = sName
                        Cells(R, 2) = .Item(N).innerText
                    Next N
                End With
            Next I
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you wanna get rid of this `------` from column B, try this:

```
With Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("p.tickeing > select > option")
    For N = 0 To .Length - 1
        If Not InStr(.Item(N).innerText, "----") > 0 Then
            R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = sName
            Cells(R, 2) = .Item(N).innerText
        End If
    Next N
End With
```

Output you may get are like:

```
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Tue, Sep 1, 08:30 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  ---------------------------------------------------------
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Wed, Sep 2, 02:00 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Wed, Sep 2, 04:15 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Wed, Sep 2, 06:30 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Wed, Sep 2, 08:45 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  ---------------------------------------------------------
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Thu, Sep 3, 02:00 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Thu, Sep 3, 04:15 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula (Laser IMAX)  Thu, Sep 3, 06:30 PM IMAX HKD 120.00 (2D Laser IMAX)
Peninsula   Tue, Sep 1, 07:20 PM House 9 HKD 105.00 (2D ATMOS)
Peninsula   Tue, Sep 1, 07:40 PM House 7 HKD 95.00 (2D)
Peninsula   Tue, Sep 1, 08:05 PM Blackbox HKD 95.00 (2D)
Peninsula   Tue, Sep 1, 08:10 PM Whitebox HKD 95.00 (2D)
Peninsula   ---------------------------------------------------------
Peninsula   Wed, Sep 2, 02:00 PM House 10 HKD 115.00 (2D ATMOS)
Peninsula   Wed, Sep 2, 02:30 PM House 2 HKD 105.00 (2D)
Peninsula   Wed, Sep 2, 03:00 PM House 9 HKD 115.00 (2D ATMOS)
Peninsula   Wed, Sep 2, 03:45 PM Blackbox HKD 105.00 (2D)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your sincerity! It does which I wanted!